# how can i install apoc in neo4j manually?

Tags: neo4j

Are there any alternative methods other than what is described in the link below to install the package?

[Installing APOC via NEO4J Desktop](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures)

Would it be possible to download from the repository? Please share any insights as to how to achieve this

Comment: Manual Installation: Download latest release - https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures#manual-installation-download-latest-release

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can download the jar file and copy the jar file into the plugins folder. Then add the following line to $NEO4J_HOME/conf/neo4j.conf and restart neo4j

```
dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=apoc.*
```

jar file:
https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/releases/3.4.0.2

Comment: I had some problems with restarting my NEO4J after making the changes. This was due to the package in this link being newer than my NEO4J installation.