# Merge Duplicate Nodes and Preserver Relationships to Nodes those duplicates were connected to

Tags: neo4j, cypher

My question is regarding how to merge multiple duplicate nodes.

Each node is, as a duplicate, connected to other nodes with a MENTIONED edge.

What I would like to do is to merge those duplicate nodes based on two properties being identical (the properties are `entity_type` and `name` so where `entity_type=entity_type` and `name=name` then merge those two nodes) and to also be able to preserve the relationships those nodes had pre-merge to other nodes on the new node. So the new merged node might have 2+ relationships to other nodes that the nodes it was merged from had.

Does anyone have any advice on how to structure this query? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **[APOC library](https://neo4j.com/developer/neo4j-apoc/)** to do this.
APOC has a procedure **`apoc.refactor.mergeNodes`** which can merge multiple duplicate nodes into one node.

All **relationships** are merged onto that node too.

**You can refer the following query to structure yours:**

```
MATCH (p:Entity)
WITH p.name AS name, p.entity_type AS type, collect(p) as nodes
CALL apoc.refactor.mergeNodes(nodes, {properties: {`.*`: 'discard'}}) YIELD node
RETURN count(node) AS new_node_count
```

Comment: Thank you @Raj. I am getting the following error.
```Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureNotFound: There is no procedure with the name `apoc.refactor.mergeNodes` registered for this database instance. Please ensure you've spelled the procedure name correctly and that the procedure is properly deployed.```

Comment: You have to install APOC, the installation process is different for Neo4j Desktop and Server. You can find both methods here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51961083/how-can-i-install-apoc-in-neo4j-manually

Comment: Ok, I think I have `dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=apoc.*` in the conf. The only thing I can think to do that might not be done is download apoc jar file and copy to plugins folder. The thing is I've already used `apoc.periodic.iterate` which I assume means I already have apoc installed. These must be additional plugins?

Comment: If you can use `apoc.periodic.iterate` then APOC is installed and don't need any other installation for `apoc.refactor.mergeNodes`.

Comment: Well, my code is here and I am getting the same error. Could it be the code?

```MATCH (e:Entity)
WITH e.name AS name, e.entity_type AS type, collect(e) as nodes
CALL apoc.refactor.mergeNodes(nodes, {properties: {author_id:'combine',author_name:'combine',entity_hash:'combine',entity_type:'combine',forum_id:'combine',name:'discard',post_id:'combine',thread_id:'combine'}}) YIELD node
RETURN count(node) AS new_node_count```

Comment: I ran `CALL dbms.procedures()` and do not see apoc.refactor.mergeNodes` listed.

Comment: Your code correct. Do you see other **apoc procedures** when you run `CALL dbms.procedures()`?

Comment: If you don't see other **APOC procedures** your installation is not complete, you might have forgot to redstart. Not sure but I'd above is not the reason then may be you are using older version.

Comment: Ok, I reinstalled apoc and still nothing. Using the latest version. Maybe it's somehow missing from the latest release `apoc-3.5.0.3-all.jar`? Neo database version if `3.5.4`.

Comment: Are facing issue using `apoc.refactor.mergeNodes` only OR other APOC procedures as well? Do you see other apoc procedures when you list procedures? I am using `apoc 3.5.0.1` & `neo4j 3.5.2` and it's working(Please check installing this apoc).

Comment: Ok, it appears that `dbms.security.procedures.whitelist=apoc.coll.*,apoc.load.*,apoc.periodic.*` 
needed to be set to `*`. At this stage it appears to be running.

Comment: However, I'm not sure if it's successfully running because the Node and Relationship counts do not appear to be decreasing. Does this  CYPHER look correct? 
```CALL apoc.periodic.iterate('
MATCH (e:Entity) WITH e.name AS name, e.entity_type AS type, collect(e) as nodes
CALL apoc.refactor.mergeNodes(nodes, {properties: {author_id:"combine",author_name:"combine",entity_hash:"combine",entity_type:"combine",forum_id:"combine",name:"discard",post_id:"combine",thread_id:"combine"}})
YIELD node RETURN count(node) AS new_node_count','', {batchSize:100000})```

Comment: You need to provide a query in the second parameter of iterate. why are you running this with iterate? is the database size too big?

Comment: There are approx. 4.7 million nodes to get through.

Comment: Can you show me where the second parameter would go?

Comment: Does anyone have any suggestion for this query?